# Работа с динамической памятью, работа деструктора (NRVO)

Tags: c++

Почему при вызове `func2()` деструктор для "a" вызывается при завершении функции, а при вызове `func()` при при завершении main?

```
class A{
public:
    ~A(){
        std::cout << "~" << std::endl;
        std::cout << *n << std::endl;
        std::cout << "END of " << n << std::endl;
        delete n;
    }
    int* n;
};


A func(){
    A a;
    a.n = new int(5);
    return a;
};

int* func2(){
    A a;
    a.n = new int(3);
    return a.n;
}


int main() {
    auto funcRes = func();
    auto func2Res = func2();
    std::cout << "func().n = " << *funcRes.n << std::endl;
    std::cout << "func2() = " << *func2Res << std::endl;
}
```

Вывод на консоль:

```
~
3
END of 0xf4fc40
func().n = 5
func2() = 0
~
5
END of 0xf4fc20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Давайте для начала разберём вариант с `func2()`. Внутри `func2()` создается локальный объект типа `A`, который как и любой локальный объект живёт только внутри блока (области видимости), в котором он определён. После выхода из этой области видимости будет вызван деструктор и объект будет уничтожен. В частности мы внутри деструктора освободим память, которая выделилась под целочисленную переменную, на которую указывает член `n`. Таким образом внутри `main` при разименовывании `*func2Res` мы будем обращаться к памяти, которая нам уже не принадлежит.

---

Что же происходит при вызове функции `func`?
На самом деле вместо того, чтобы создавать новый объект внутри `main` с помощью конструктора копирования будет использован тот объект, который был создан внутри функции `func`. Эта оптимизация называется [NRVO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_value_optimization) (Named return value optimization). Немножко подробнее:

RVO(return value optimization) позволяет компилятору оптимизировать следующие конструкции:

```
class A{};
A func() {
    return A(); // будет вызван конструктор
}
int main() {
    A a = func(); // конструктор вызван не будет, так как сработала оптимизация
}
```

NRVO расширяет возможности оптимизации и позволяет компилятору оптимизировать не только возвращение объектов созданных непосредственно при вызове `return`, но и разных именованных значений, которые былии объявлены в этой функции раньше:

```
class A{};
A func() {
    A a; // конструктор будет вызван только тут
    return a; 
}
int main() {
    A a = func() // конструктор копирования не будет вызван. сработает NRVO
}
```

Что касается стандарта, то он неь гарантирует, что компилятор должен оптимизировать подобные выражения, но разрешает иметь им такое поведение. Смотреть [12.8.*](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf)

Подробнее:
1. [Named Return Value Optimization in Visual C++](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms364057(vs.80).aspx)
2. [RVO и NRVO](http://alenacpp.blogspot.ru/2008/02/rvo-nrvo.html)

Answer (score 0):

Обратите внимание, что в вопросе вы все перепутали. `func()` инициализируется пятеркой, а на печать деструктор сначала выводит тройку. Значит, когда вызывается `func()` как раз деструктор не вызывается - он вызывается в конце `main`.

Это потому, что работает RVO (оптимизация возвращаемого значения) - при возврате экземпляра объекта не происходит его пересоздания, при вызове `func`, `A` создается сразу внутри funcRes

А в случае с `func2()`, где как раз фигурирует тройка, `a` живет только на время существования тела функции `func2();`

Отсюда порядок работы

`А(5)` создалось сразу в `funcRes`

Создалось `A(3)`

Уничтожилось `A(3)`

Уничтожилось `funcRes(5)`